# How to add CSS classes to a Views-generated block? (NOT to its generated content, the block itself!)

Tags: 7, views, blocks, theming

I don't know why, but Views doesn't add "human-readable" CSS class names (like e.g. the machine name of the view) to the blocks it creates (**it only adds its classes to the *generated "content" part*** when adding classes to the "*CSS class*" part in the view editor (see the screenshots below!)).
It only adds the usual `block block-views`, and possibly `contextual-links-region` CSS classes to the block(s), and generates a unique id (not class) like this: `block-views-3d8f7966168beeec655c8ead69336789` (because its delta is this generated hash code).
It doesn't make sense to write CSS rules for these classes and ids (like `.block-views-3d8f7966168beeec655c8ead69336789 { /* ... */ }`), because these classes/ids might change when altering the Views block.

How can I add some custom CSS classes in an implementation of `hook_block_view_alter()`, if I cannot even identify these blocks because of their generated hash delta?

---

**I do not want to use [Block Class](http://drupal.org/project/block_class)**, because I feel it's like an overkill for just adding some classes to one or two Views-generated blocks (BTW I checked the module, and I feel `SELECT css_class, module, delta FROM {block_class}` query in `block_class_preprocess_block()` like an overkill, because it checks ALL the added classes, even if the block is hidden...).

So I would like to solve it from my own module.

---

EDIT

An example:

My view with the machine name and the added CSS classes:
[image: View - machine name and class]

The generated block's HTML code in the inspector:
[image: View - generated block's HTML code in the inspector]

Answer (score 7):

First. You have "hash" - because you view machine name is too long.

Second - you can add your own classes to view

[image]

Comment: That screenshot you have regards view blocks, right?

Comment: no - it is on view editing page  - admin/structure/views/view/[youviewname]

Comment: _"You have "hash" - because you view machine name is too long."_ - and why does it matter? I can add rules in CSS stylesheets to REALLY long class names too without any problems... The _"CSS class"_ part you marked is NOT correct, because these classes are only generated into the "content" part - this is what I started my question with! So I have to add classes to the **wrapper** of the contents. See the screenshots I just pasted in the original question.

Comment: ok. in this case the simpliest way is to create custom templates for block - you want change.

this link can be useful http://drupal.org/node/1089656 - it explains Template name suggestions

Comment: But this way I had to use a `block--views--3d8f7966168beeec655c8ead69336789.tpl.php` file, and in this case, I'm at the same point as if I used an `if($variables['block']->delta == '3d8f7966168beeec655c8ead69336789')` condition in `hook_preprocess_block()`. This is what I wanted to avoid, because I thought I can use a more human-readable name in my hook. For example, what if I want to move the view into another with the same parameters, I delete the previous one, but use the same machine name and CSS classes, but the generated unique hash changes? In this case, I lose my modifications.

Comment: try this block--views--view_machine_name.tpl.php

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately it doesn't work. (Yes, I even cleared cache.)

Comment: @cherouvim: yes, the screenshot that Gaydabura showed, regards Views blocks.

Answer (score 2):

That's a old question, but there is no proper answer. I came across the same problem. The solutions I could think of was CSS parent selector (which doesn't exists yet) OR some Drupal manipulation.

I added a hook_preprocess_block to add a wrapper CSS class to all view blocks that define a CSS class. That's not trivial so I will put my code here. It may not work with all view blocks, if you have an issue with this code, feel free to update it and post your own version.

Example: View with CSS class "test" will be contained in a block with the CSS class "test-wrapper".

```
function <MY_THEME>_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    $default_display_id = 'default';
    // Trying to access the field:
    //     $display_id =      $variables['elements']['#views_contextual_links_info']['views_ui']['view_display_id']
    //     $default_display = $variables['elements']['#views_contextual_links_info']['views_ui']['view']->display['default']->display_options['css_class']
    //     $display =         $variables['elements']['#views_contextual_links_info']['views_ui']['view']->display[$display_id]->display_options['css_class']
    if (isset($variables['elements']['#views_contextual_links_info']['views_ui'])) {
        $view_ui = $variables['elements']['#views_contextual_links_info']['views_ui'];
        if (isset($view_ui['view_display_id'])) {
            $display_id = $view_ui['view_display_id'];
            if (isset($view_ui['view']) && property_exists($view_ui['view'], 'display') && isset($view_ui['view']->display[$display_id])) {

                $default_css_class = NULL;
                if (isset($view_ui['view']->display[$default_display_id])) {
                    $default_display = $view_ui['view']->display[$default_display_id];
                    if (property_exists($default_display, 'display_options') && isset($default_display->display_options['css_class'])) {
                        $default_css_class = $default_display->display_options['css_class'];
                    }
                }

                $view_css_class = NULL;
                $display = $view_ui['view']->display[$display_id];
                if (property_exists($display, 'display_options') && isset($display->display_options['css_class'])) {
                    $view_css_class = $display->display_options['css_class'];
                }

                $css_class = $view_css_class ? $view_css_class : $default_css_class;
                if ($css_class) {
                    $variables['classes_array'][] = "$css_class-wrapper";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for this purpose.

[View block top class](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewblock_topclass)

[image: Screenshot from module page]

Answer (score 1):

For me [`hook_preprocess_block()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7) didn't work. (Maybe because I had to add the block directly from a template file via [`views_embed_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7).)

However, [`hook_preprocess_views_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/7) with a simple check for `$vars['view']->current_display` did work:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  // 'MYBLOCK' usually comes as 'block' if this view only has one
  if ($vars['view']->name == 'MYVIEW' && $vars['view']->current_display == 'MYBLOCK') {
    // here I add a class that contains the current theme's name
    global $theme;
    $theme_name = array_pop(explode('/', (drupal_get_path('theme', $theme))));
    $vars['classes_array'][] = $theme_name.'-theme';
    // but you can simply do the following as well
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'MYSTRING';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me was to duplicate the file block.tpl.php, rename it to `block--myregion.tpl.php` and then add my classes inside it.

See: [Theming blocks page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/theming-blocks).